# When to use Option#orNull

Tags: scala, scala-option

As I understand we should avoid using `null` in Scala. And if some field is not logically valid to have "no-value" then we should not use `Option` to avoid overusing of `Option`s.

So lets look to code. 
I have class

```
case class User (name: String)
```

and I 100% sure that `name` field can not be `null`, and because of it I used just `String` instead of `Option[String]`.

The problem is that some standard Scala methods return to me `Option`s. (In my case the `IterableLike#find` method returns Option)

So the question is how I can create `User` instance when I have the `name` wrapped to `Option`? 
To be a little clear this is the code:

```
val userName: Option[String] = myList.find(...)
val user = User(userName.get) // or may be I should use userName.orNull ? or throw exception?
```

I heard that `Option.get` is not elegant solution. `orNull`method is almost same as `get`.

Comment: You're 100% sure that `name` cannot be `None`, but are you 100% sure `name` is in `myList`? Wouldn't you want to make it an `Option[User]`, depending on whether the `User` is found by name?

Comment: They're both terrible, but `orNull` is worse than `get`. `get` on a `None` just throws an exception immediately, while `orNull` sets a landmine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`orNull` is provided largely for Java interoperability.  The use of `null` as a sentinel value in many Java libraries is pervasive and `orNull` serves as a small piece of syntactic sugar.  Essentially it's just `myOption.getOrElse(null)` but with a function name that allows for slightly cleaner code.

The use of `orNull` in a pure Scala project would be odd to say the least.

Answer (score 9):

You want to map your `Option[String]` to a `Option[User]`:

```
val userName: Option[String] = myList.find(...)
val user: Option[User] = userName.map(n => User(n))
```

Comment: Extremely elegant. This actually uses the `Option` coming back from the `find()` to _enhance_ the code, rather than ugly it up :-)